Can we keep the loan after the house/apartment has been sold?
Assuming I buy a house with a loan, can I sell the house/apartment and keep the loan to buy something else in another country where a loan's interest is much higher?
Japan: loan on 35years are ~0.5%
Europe: loan are more around single digit %
I believe it isn't allowed but any similar stories where it was possible?

Are you talking about mortgage loans? Those usually require... mortgage? If you sell the property, what would be the collateral?

You usually can't sell the property without the lender knowing (and accepting), and they will usually get the money from the sale to repay the loan, so the loan would be terminated.

Also consider the fact that currency exchange variations may make the proposition very risky even if it was possible. Over the last 5 years, there's a 50% difference between the max and min EUR/JPY exchange rate. There are cross-border workers between France and Switzerland who have been badly burned by variations of the EUR/CHF rate.

There may be countries where this is possible where the loan deal is transferable to another property withing their jurisdiction.

and keep the loan to buy something else in another country where a
loan's interest is much higher?

That makes it impossible. The lender would have limited resources to evaluate the property as collateral. They would have to seize property in another country if you stop making payments.

Japan: loan on 35 years are ~0.5% Europe: loan are more around single digit %

If they wanted to try this, their risks would be higher and they would want to charge a much higher rate to compensate for that risk.

That's what I thought but also just wanted to ask. Thanks!
